# Why does a navbar when fixed to the top (with position:fixed) requires the width property?

Tags: css, position

Simple fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/75zwpy3b/2/

The navbar is styled as

```
#navbar {
        background-color: #333;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 70px;
        /* width: 100%; */
        position: fixed; 
      }
```

As you can see the width has not been applied but position:fixed is applied, the navbar contracts to fit its content, but if i comment out position:fixed then suddenly the navbar goes all the way from left to right.

Why does position:fixed requires width:100% to go with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it´s fixed it doesn't know of its parent elements or siblings so it just fits the width to its contents. One solution is to go **width: 100%** or **left: 0; right: 0;**

Comment: If i use width:100% then 100% of what ? the parent element or the viewport ?
And if i use left: 0; right: 0; then those are again w.r.t the view-port or the parent element and
those are the coordinates of the leftmost point of the navbar and the right most point of the navbar respectively right ?

Comment: @TarunSingh That will be of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting a fixed position it needs a height and width property since there are no other defined elements to go off of. If you want the nav to scale across the screen then use width: 100% but if you wanted a specific fixed nav size you could do width: 800px.